# how to list all existing presamples campaigns in brigthway project

Tags: brightway

How can I list all existing `presamples` campaigns in my brighway2 project? :)

I've been checking [the documentation](https://presamples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=campaign#using-campaigns-to-manage-sets-of-presample-packages) but I can't find how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Campaign` is a [normal](https://github.com/PascalLesage/presamples/blob/master/presamples/campaigns.py#L36) [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) `Model`, so you can follow the peewee [querying patterns](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#selecting-multiple-records), e.g. `[obj.name for obj in Campaign.select()]`.